# Istio - Can't see default metrics in Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, istio

I'm having some issues understanding the following.

I'm trying to look up for the `"istio_requests_total"` metric in Prometheus, using K8s and Istio. But when I go to the Prometheus instance, that metric it's just not there (under Prometheus > Graph > Expression field).

See capture for where it should the metric be and it's not:
[image: See capture for where it should the metric be and it's not]

So, I have make a lab environment, in which, following the documentation you deploy Prometheus for Istio.

https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/integrations/prometheus/

And in this environment, the metric "istio_requests_total" is there without having to do anything else.

So I have deep dive into the Prometheus pod created in this demo environment, trying to search from where this metric is configured but didn't have any success yet.

***Why am I doing this?***

If I'm not wrong, I can use that metric to measure incoming traffic into my services and therefore have a monitoring metric.
As I didn't found the metric in my env, I went to create the demo environment to see if I could obtain that configuration and then replicate it into my desired environment

So, my questions in case anybody can shed some light on this are

- From where that metric (and default istio metrics) are configured? Is there any file with those settings?
- Is there any step I have missed?

Have to admin that all of these is fairly new to me, so probably I might doing something wrong. So I'm grateful for any indication on how to approach this.

cheers

Comment: Which version of Istio and Kubernetes did you use? How did you deploy your cluster?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak 
```# Istio version
# I've obtained this by checking the istio-proxy sidecar logs
Version 1.4.10```

```# K8s version
# I've obtained this by executing kubectl version
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20+", GitVersion:"v1.20.8-gke.700"```

About how do I deployed the cluster...what do you mean exactly?

Regards

Comment: How do you deploy the cluster means did you use some cloud provider (which?) or did you set up bare metal cluster? :)

Comment: Are you able to see other istio and envoy related metrics, or you see none of envoy/istio metrics? In that case it is a setup issue. For every istio version check which version of prometheus is supported. Hope you are not deploying latest prometheus with istio 1.4

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak Hi, ohh yeah, GCP and Terraform.

Comment: @nitgeek I can see some other metrics, so that could be it. Prometheus version is 2.15.1